# how to update existing records while copying data from source table to destination table in ssis package

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

```
MERGE INTO cms_universal_metadata AS Target
USING cms_universal_metadata_stage AS Source
ON Target.asset_folder_hash =Source.stg_asset_folder_hash
-- AND Target.Mid =Source.Mid 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET Target.asset_folder_path = Source.stg_asset_folder_path ,
Target.a_archive = Source.stg_a_archive,
Target.acl_name = Source.stg_acl_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
INSERT (asset_folder_path,a_archive,acl_name)
VALUES (Source.stg_asset_folder_path,Source.stg_a_archive,Source.stg_a_archive);
```

i have a automation ssis package in that  need to copy from staging table  to destination table .If again copying from staging to destination that time if same record is there it should be update or else it will be insert.please anybody help to me?

Comment: I also don't understand the question. Please include your code, and try to format your question more clearly.

Comment: I hope now every now will understand

Comment: The above code is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try `Lookup transformation` with `OLEDB command` transformation to update existing records.

**Learn about:**

Slowly changing dimensions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141715.aspx

T-SQL MERGE - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you search is called `Upsert` there are many tuto in the net some link as bellow must help you :

[SSIS Upsert With Lookup Transform](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html)

[Upsert and Merge with SSIS](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/ssis/upsert-merge-with-integration-services)